# How can we run one spring batch app on 2 different instances in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which is doing ETL. To improve the speed I am planning to 2 instances in parallel with 2 servers.

How can I configure those two instance to copy different set of data and not same data?

Answer (score 1):

You can find informations about scalability here :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

In your case I suggest you to look at remote chunking. But have you tried partionning before ? It can increase performance a lot and i think it's the first thing to do (and it's easier).

Comment: So if I have 10 data items, I should process distinct 5 on each instance. Is that what you mean by partitioning?